# In Twitter Bootstrap, should a Grid Column be its own special Div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

When using Twitter bootstrap's grid system, should every grid column div (with the class `span*`) have `span*` class as its only class, like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="sidebar">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
        <div class="content">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or can we mix `span*` class with other classes, like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4 sidebar">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="span8 content">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

`.sidebar` and `.content` are CSS rules and not simply for Javascript/CSS rule traversal or used as IDs.

Comment: You can 'mix' them. The other way could lead to a case of divitus.

Comment: You may do whatever you want, as long as the result is consistent with your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what those other classes do.

If `.sidebar` and `.content` are used exclusively to scope CSS inside those divs, or if they are labels for javascript traversal, then you are probably fine using them.

However, if you have rules attached to these classes that impact layout such as width, height, margin, and so on, you may experience problems.